# Bank account Classes. How to make it more powerful/efficient? (OOP)

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

I want to make this program work without using global variables. Basically, if the person withdraws and ends up going in negative figures, they incur a penalty of 5. Every transaction that's in minus will also cause a penalty of 5.

The program seems to work fine assuming there are only 2 accounts:

```
account1 = Bankaccount(20)
account2 = Bankaccount(5)
```

but thats its limitation. How can I allow infinite accounts? So I don't get constrained to the two globals. I hope this makes sense, assume I have to change withdrawal function and get_fees, but I'm new to OOP so I'm stuck. Thanks for your help!

```
pen = 0
pen2 = 0


class BankAccount:


 def __init__(self, initial_balance):
        """Creates an account with the given balance."""
        self.money = initial_balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposits the amount into the account."""
        self.money += amount
        return self.money

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """
        Withdraws the amount from the account.  Each withdrawal resulting in a
        negative balance also deducts a penalty fee of 5 dollars from the balance.
        """
        global pen, pen2
        penalty = 5

        if self.money - amount < 0:
            self.money -= (amount + penalty)
            if self == account1:
                pen += 5
            elif self == account2:
                pen2 += 5
        else:
            self.money -= amount
        return self.money


    def get_balance(self):
        """Returns the current balance in the account."""
        return self.money

    def get_fees(self):
        """Returns the total fees ever deducted from the account."""
        global pen, pen2
        if self == account1:
            return pen
        elif self == account2:
            return pen2
```

Comment: why won't you add `pen` attibute to account?

Comment: Why don't you have a dictionary where keys are the account name and values are a BankAccount object that only tracks itself?

Comment: Typically one uses a `list` to store an indefinite number of items. E.g. `accounts = [BankAccount(100), BankAccount(200), BankAccount(333)]`. A dictionary is another possibility: `accounts = {'FooAccount': BankAccount(10), 'BarAccount': BankAccount(20)}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the penalty a instance attribute, just as `money` is:

```
def __init__(self, initial_balance):
        """Creates an account with the given balance."""
        self.money = initial_balance
        self.penalty = 0
```

And, later on:

```
def withdraw(self, amount):

    if self.money - amount < 0:
        self.penalty += 5
```

Comment: Not a class attribute, an instance attribute!

Comment: Apologies! Picked the wrong name (but wrote correct code :>), you're right of course. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Thats so simple, can't believe I didnt think of that :)!

Answer (score 4):

Just turn the global variables into instance variables:

```
class BankAccount:
    PENALTY = 5
    def __init__(self, initial_balance):
        """Creates an account with the given balance."""
        self.money = initial_balance
        self.penalty = 0

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposits the amount into the account."""
        self.money += amount
        return self.money

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """
        Withdraws the amount from the account.  Each withdrawal resulting in a
        negative balance also deducts a penalty fee of 5 dollars from the balance.
        """
        if self.money - amount < 0:
            self.money -= (amount + BankAccount.PENALTY)
            self.penalty += BankAccount.PENALTY
        else:
            self.money -= amount
        return self.money


    def get_balance(self):
        """Returns the current balance in the account."""
        return self.money

    def get_fees(self):
        """Returns the total fees ever deducted from the account."""
        return self.penalty
```

I also noticed you declared a variable called `penalty` in the `withdraw` function. This looks like the beginning of good practice in avoiding [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants), so I continued along those lines by making it a constant attribute of the `BankAccount` class.

Also, in Python we don't usually use functions just to access attributes. Instead of `bobs_account.get_fees()` it would be more normal to do `bobs_account.penalty`.

Comment: You could make the PENALTY a class attribute, moving it inside `BankAccount`

Comment: Awesome, thank you for showing me this code. Yeah it was actually part of a quiz that I was doing but I wanted to see if there was a 'better' way to do it so ignore the functions which accesses the attributes. But I will bare that in mind in the future (once I get the gist of OOP)

Answer (score 3):

The penalty should also be an instance variable of a `BankAccount` object:

```
class BankAccount:
    penalty_amount = 5

    def __init__(self, initial_balance):
        self.money = initial_balance
        self.penalty = 0

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """
        Withdraws the amount from the account.  Each withdrawal resulting in a
        negative balance also deducts a penalty fee of 5 dollars from the balance.
        """

        if self.money - amount < 0:
            self.money -= (amount + BankAccount.penalty_amount)
            self.penalty += BankAccount.penalty_amount

        else:
            self.money -= amount
        return self.money
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :), I didn't know you could do that! Will bare this in mind for future reference.

Comment: I think you mean class variable (or attribute), not instance variable!

Answer (score 0):

```
class BankAccount:

 accounts = {}
 def __init__(self,account_id, initial_balance):
       BankAccount.accounts[account_id] = self
       ...

 @classmethod
 def get_account(cls,acct_id):
      return BankAccount.accounts.get(acct_id)
```

something like this perhaps

```
BankAccount(1,20)
print BankAccount.get_account(1)
BankAccount("apple",100)
print BankAccount.get_account("apple")
```

this is one way to address multiple accounts, follow the other advice with respect to the penalty

Comment: Thank you! Appretiate your answer :)

Comment: I haven't learnt about @classmethod. What does it do in this instance?

Comment: it makes it so you can call the method without an instance of the class but rather the class itself (`BankAccount.get_account('some_id')` instead of `BankAccount(100).some_method()`)